# How to call a method by name with different signatures in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, algorithm, typescript, angular-http

I'm trying to set up a method that call my back-end and do generic stuff for me.

So I come to this code:

```
myFct() {
    this[type](url, params, options).pipe(...)
}

get<T>(url: string, params: HttpParams, options: any): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
    return this._http.get<T>(url, options);
}

post<T>(url: string, params: HttpParams, options: any): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
    return this._http.post<T>(url, params, options);
}

put<T>(url: string, params: HttpParams, options: any): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
    return this._http.put<T>(url, params, options);
}

delete<T>(url: string, params: HttpParams, options: any): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
    return this._http.delete<T>(url, options);
}
```

But I found that 4 method is redundant and I would like to know if there a way of doing that directly:

```
this._http[type](url, params, options)
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature
```

Because **GET** and **DELETE** doesn't have a **HttpParams** in their signature.

Is their a way that I can return parameters based on a condition? Or return two parameters and it match with the signature?

Comment: Where does `type` come from? Can you post a simple example the replicated this error?

Comment: it's a string that can be 'get, 'put', 'post' or 'delete'

Comment: Then it shouldn't be an error, since all your functions take 3 arguments... **edit:** oops I didn't see the change to call `this._http` instead of `this`... makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that the [`.length` property of a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) returns the number of arguments it takes, and do:

```
(this._http[type].length === 3 ? 
    this._http[type](url, params, options) : 
    this._http[type](url, options));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't type check in TypeScript unless the OP merges in a type declaration for the `length` property of each method in `HttpClient` (or just does type assertions)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine a helper that captures the type, declaration merging, and mapped types to achieve the desired effect. Unfortunately

```
type Method = 'post' | 'put' | 'delete' | 'get';

type R = {
    [M in Method]: (this: { http: HttpClient }, method: M) => typeof this['http'][M]
};

interface MyHttp extends R { }

class MyHttp {
    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
        Object.assign(
          this, (<Method[]>['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'])
            .map(method => http[method].bind(http))
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe using function overloads would get what you want:

```
myFct<T>(type: "get" | "delete", url: string, options: any): Observable<HttpEvent<T>>;
myFct<T>(type: "post" | "put", url: string, params: HttpParams, options: any): Observable<HttpEvent<T>>;
myFct<T>(type: "get" | "delete" | "post" | "put", url: string, paramsOrOptions: HttpParams | any, options?: any): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
    return type == "get" || type == "delete"
        ? this._http[type](url, paramsOrOptions)
        : this._http[type](url, paramsOrOptions, options) 
}


http.myFct<any>("get", "http://", {}) // OK
http.myFct<any>("get", "http://", {}, {}) // Error (too many args)
http.myFct<any>("post", "http://", {}, {}) // OK
http.myFct<any>("post", "http://", {}) // Error (too few args)
```

Although, personally, I'm not sure this is really any better than just having 4 functions.